# What is it called when you can't tell a person's age?

Tags: single-word-requests

So if androgynous means visibly indeterminate gender, what would you call someone of visibly indeterminate age?

> "I can't tell that Asian guy's age. He's [age-ogynous]."

Comment: The original example is flawed. I would say: "I've no idea how old that Asian guy is - He could be any age."

Answer (score 1):

Illusive. I couldn't tell her age so her age was illusive, or her appearance, perhaps, was illusive, making it difficult to tell her age. I think illusive is the word but I didn't find it anywhere but from some obscure memory in my mind of having read it in a book once. :)

Comment: Hello, Tiffany. If 'illusive' is a valid answer, it should be easy to look it up in an online dictionary. An answer without reasonable research, quoted, attributed and linked, is not what ELU is after.

Answer (score 1):

While "indeterminate age" is accurate and correct English, it does not sound like something I would hear in  conversation (USA).

Meaning exactly the same would be the more colloquial "uncertain age".

The most famous quote I can think of is Proust's "“She was "a woman of uncertain age.”

Note:  "Uncertain age" is also used to refer to a period of time, as used by Robert 
Frost:

*If this uncertain age in which we dwell
Were really as dark as I hear sages tell,
And I convinced that they were really sages,
I should not curse myself with it to hell.*

Robert Frost

"The Lesson for Today" (1942).

Also "Peter Pan Syndrome" which is not a standard phrase, but refers to the character in the story of Peter Pan who said, "I won't grow up" in the song in the musical.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options:

Perennial - existing or continuing in the same way for a long time

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perennial

Timeless - staying beautiful or fashionable as time passes

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/timeless

Comment: Would you describe a person as "perennial" or "timeless"?

Comment: I think it is about established moulds. One might describe qualities of a person if not the person itself, using the aforementioned words. What do you think?

Comment: Or were you asking me choose between those two?

Comment: I think you might perhaps use those terms in a poetic or literary context, but they would sound really  queer and unusual in ordinary speech, which is what OP is actually referring to.

Comment: @Josh61 What about using "timeless" here? It doesn't seem so inappropriate. Or does it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's be as accurate as possible.  If you're looking for **a single word**, an adjective, for a person whose age is difficult to determine just by their looks, I dare say there isn't such a word.

But you might say: "His age? I couldn't possibly tell. He seems to be one of those persons who never look their age."

Answer (score 0):

a person of indeterminate age

American Heritage Dictionary:

in·de·ter·mi·nate  (ĭn′dĭ-tûrmə-nĭt)
Share: Tweet
adj.
1.
a. Not precisely determined, determinable, or established: a person of indeterminate age.
[indeterminate](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=indeterminate)

Also in BrE

That is the usual idiom.

Comment: "He is of indeterminate age" is quite formal (and a little old-fashioned) and does not seem to fit the context.

Comment: @Greybeard androgynous is also formal. Informal is: can't tell their sex or gender, can't tell their age. As for old fashioned, that is simply not true.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps ["***ageless***"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ageless)or "possessing a timeless quality":

> - not growing old or showing the effects of age.

(Merriam-Webster)

Comment: Eh. People use "ageless" to describe things that are very old. Not quite the same as *can't tell their age*. What about petite, smooth-faced women that look anywhere between 15 and 35? "Ageless" doesn't seem like the right description for them.